# What is the difference between QItemDelegate and QStyledItemDelegate?

Tags: c++, qt, qitemdelegate, qstyleditemdelegate

Both classes provide display and editing facilities for data items from a model. `QStyledItemDelegate`  is newer and the Qt documentation about `QItemDelegate` states that :

> Note that QStyledItemDelegate has taken over the job of drawing Qt's
>   item views. We recommend the use of QStyledItemDelegate when creating
>   new delegates.

I am confused what's the difference between the two and why `QStyledItemDelegate` is preferred over `QItemDelegate`!

Comment: Just to double check, have you checked the `QStyledItemDelegate vs. QItemDelegate` section of the http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstyleditemdelegate.html docs?

Comment: @luliu I have missed that part. Thanks.

Comment: From the QItemDelegate documentation :
"""
The difference between them is that QStyledItemDelegate uses the
current style to paint its items. We therefore recommend using
QStyledItemDelegate as the base class when implementing custom
delegates or when working with Qt style sheets.
"""
So if you are using a style sheet it won't have effects on the widgets made by a `QItemDelegate`. That's why Qt recommends using the `QStyledItemDelegate` instead.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As mentioned in the [`QStyledItemDelegate` documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstyleditemdelegate.html#qstyleditemdelegate-vs-qitemdelegate), the difference is that `QStyledItemDelegate` uses the current style to paint its items.

> These two classes are independent alternatives to painting and
>   providing editors for items in views. The difference between them is
>   that **`QStyledItemDelegate` uses the current style** to paint its items. We
>   therefore recommend using `QStyledItemDelegate` as the base class when
>   implementing custom delegates or when working with Qt style sheets.
>   The code required for either class should be equal unless the custom
>   delegate needs to use the style for drawing.

*Note that this answer is based on the comments of Iuliu and Alex*